# Javascript: can't access object property through for..in loop

Tags: javascript, html, css, object, for-in-loop

I am trying to access a property (name) on an object that is in fact located inside another object. I initialized the object in a file:

```
var icons = {

    "facebook": {name: 'facebook', icon_url: 'img/logos/facebook.png'}

};
```

And then tried to check the object with this code:

```
   var icon_current_class;

  for(var icon in icons){

    console.dir(icon);
    //outputs an object named facebook but says it has no properties

    if( $(this).hasClass( icon.name ) ){
      icon_current_class = icon.name;
    }else{
      alert("Something went wrong. Please contact the mods.");
    }
  }
```

And of course, the alert("Something went wrong") goes off everytime I run this. I have tried for a long time to find a solution, but to no avail. Can anyone please help?

Comment: JavaScript's `in` is always for keys rather than values.

Comment: You should just read the `for...in` documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`for(var x in y)` `x` is the key of the object, you need to use `y[x]` to return the value:

```
for(var icon_name in icons){
    var icon = icons[icon_name];
    .....code....
}
```

Comment: Is there an echo in here?

Comment: ahaha thank you too! You actually explained the code you wrote, so thank you so much!

Comment: @popnoodles i actually started typing my answer before yours, but my wifi dropped, you should get the answer tho.

Answer (score 6):

```
for(var icon in icons)
```

In the for loop, `icon` you're assigned there isn't an object, it's the index/key of each item.

```
for (var i in icons){
    console.dir(icons[i]);
...
```

Comment: Hmm, it didn't set in my mind why this worked yet, but thank you so much for the fast answer! :)